# Use of tenant_id in multi-tenant database

Tags: database-design, multitenancy

We are building a SASS web application where every company will be using its own database schema. Using postgresql, there is a table 'companies' in the public schema that holds the name of the company and the name of the schema to switch to. In the tenant schema there are a lot of tables that store data specific to this company. Every request, the tenant schema is set based upon the current company as stored in a session.

The internal discussion is this one:

Should the tables in the tenant schema have a `company_id` column to denote the relation between the data and the company? Or is the current company implied by the used schema, and is it overkill to use the `company_id` in every table that has a relation with a company?

**Opinion 1**

The first opinion is that the relations between the company and other tables should be defined explicitly in the table structure. This also enables ActiveRecord queries like: `current_company.projects.find(3)`. Referential integrity is enforced, even for relations that cross the schema boundary.

**Opinion 2**

The second opinion is that it would be better to drop all `company_id` columns in all tables because when you switch to a tenant schema, you will never be able to get data from other companies. The same ActiveRecord query must now be written as `Project.find(3)`. The company is implied by the chosen schema, not through a relation. Also, dropping the `company_id` column from every table would save disk space.

Which approach do you think is best?

Comment: Disk space is probably the least of your concerns

Comment: define the relationships explicitly, who knows when you might need it?

Answer (score 2):

A schema in Postgresql is akin to a "database" in, say, MySQL; it is a namespace containing a distinct and separate collection of database objects (tables, views, stored procedures, triggers, etc).  Creating a schema for each tenant will allow you to

- Hold a database connection open and switch between schemas,
- Query across multiple tenants using UNION, and
- Avoid problems where someone changes the ID and accesses the data of some other company.

If you create a schema for each company, you won't need company_id fields in each table; the schema will provide the necessary separation.  Your ActiveRecord query will look something like `company.Projects.find(3)`, where `company` is the name of the schema corresponding to that particular tenant.